# Android: Does Alarm Manager get killed if the application get kill by system

Tags: android, alarmmanager, low-memory

My Receiver will load when device got boot up and start the alarm manager to schedule every 10second to check my other service is still running. Now I wonder will the Alarm Receiver get killed or stop receiving broadcast if memory low. 
Cos i need constantly check my other service are still available and not get killed by the system. If I the service got destroy or not restart again, the alarm receiver can start the service automatically).

Comment: If your service returns `START_STICKY` then it will always be working in the background and if the system has stopped your app for memory reasons the service will be started again when memory will free up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Broadcast Receiver (in particular, an Alarm Receiver) can be killed by the system in cases of "extreme memory pressure". That is: it will not happen in regular situations, but it *could* happen.

> Process Lifecycle
>
> A process that is currently executing a BroadcastReceiver (that is,
>   currently running the code in its onReceive(Context, Intent) method)
>   is considered to be a foreground process and will be kept running by
>   the system except under cases of extreme memory pressure.

From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ProcessLifecycle).

Comment: Is there a good way to prevent that happen coz i need to listen UDP packets to constantly checking the other device controls e.g. the user touches the edit text field, this will send a data packet to my device so my my device can react and display a keyboard. if AlarmReceiver will get destroy then I don't bother to write that AlarmReceiver.

Comment: There is no way to prevent that from happening. Android will decide when an Alarm Receiver can be killed. It won't happen regularly, so maybe coding the Alarm Receiver is still worth the pain.

Comment: Sorry not understand the last phrase coz english wasn't my first language 'worth the pain' does that mean still worth to have it???

Comment: Yes, I think it is worth to have it. A service can be killed for a number of reasons different to being out of memory. If you feel the answer I provided was correct, please mark it as useful.